# User validation not working properly in CakePHP through the User Model

Tags: php, cakephp, model, cakephp-1.3

For some reason, I can't get this validation to work as I'd like it to, specifically with the password minLength field.

Everything else is fine (even the minLength for Username works). For some reason, when I add the same minLength rule into the password field, it just ignores it and when I actually do enter in a password, it tells me that I need to enter a password:

```
    var $validate = array(
'email' => array(
    'email' => array(
        'rule' => array('email', true),
        'required' => true,
        'allowEmpty' => false,
        'message' => 'Please enter a valid email address'
    ),
    'isUnique' => array(
        'rule' => 'isUnique',
        'message' => 'This email is already in use'
    )
),
'username' => array(
    'notEmpty' => array(
        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
        'required' => true,
        'message' => 'Please enter a valid username'
    ),
    'allowedCharacters' => array(
        'rule' => '/^[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*$/',
        'message' => 'Please enter a valid username'
    ),
    'minLength' => array(
        'rule' => array('minLength', 3),
        'message' => 'Please enter a longer username'
    ),
    'maxLength' => array(
        'rule' => array('maxLength', 23),
        'message' => 'Please enter a shorter username'
    ),
    'isUnique' => array(
        'rule' => 'isUnique',
        'message' => 'That username is already taken'
    )
),
'password' => array(
    'notEmpty' => array(
        'required' => true,
        'allowEmpty' => false,
        'message' => 'Please enter a password'
    ),
    'minLength' => array(
        'rule' => array('minLength', 4),
        'message' => 'Please enter a longer password'
    ),
     'passwordConfirm' => array(
        'rule' => array('checkPasswords'),
        'message' => 'Passwords must match'

       )
    ),
   );
```

Am I overlooking something minor? It's driving me nuts.

Comment: Try to remove nonEmpty rule and check what happens ?

Comment: @riky It skips all the password validation entirely if I remove that rule.

Comment: Than you must check the db name and your field name ? I hope it is right

Comment: you should also use last=>true here! otherwise it doesnt make much sense

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because in Cake, the password field is automatically hashed as soon as you submit it; which will break your validation rules (a 5 character password suddenly becomes a 40+ digit hash). There are various proposed [fixes for this problem](http://cakephp.1045679.n5.nabble.com/How-to-validate-password-length-td1305652.html).

One that sounds the most promising:

Create two fields e.g `pw` and `pw_confirm` as opposed to `password` and `confirm_password`. Use these values for your password validation (so, max length etc)

Then something like:

```
$this->User->set($this->data);
if ($this->User->validates()) {
    // all your data validates, so hash the password submitted,
    // ready for storage as normal.
    $password_hash = $this->Auth->password($this->data['User']['pw'];
    $this->data['User']['password'] = $password_hash;
}
```

This way, Cake won't automatically hash the passed that's entered - allowing your validation to function as you intended.

To visualise this, add this to your `register`/`add user` method:

```
function admin_add() {
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        debug($this->data); 
        exit;
```

You'll get:

```
Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [username] => somename
            [password] => 25ae3c1689d26b20e03abc049982349482faa64e
        )

)
```

before validation takes place.

Comment: I wonder why CakePHP decided for this approach since it seems more problematic than helpful.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have a small mistake in your validation array.

Every validation for a field must have a 'rule' key, and you don't have that in your 'notEmpty' validation.

Try updating the password validation like this:

```
<?php
array(
'password' => array(
    'notEmpty' => array(
        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
        'required' => true,
        'allowEmpty' => false,
        'message' => 'Please enter a password'
    ),
    'minLength' => array(
        'rule' => array('minLength', 4),
        'message' => 'Please enter a longer password'
    ),
     'passwordConfirm' => array(
        'rule' => array('checkPasswords'),
        'message' => 'Passwords must match'

       )
))
?>
```

Also, note that if you're using the Auth component your password will be hashed BEFORE it is validated. This means that even if you enter a 3-character password you'll end up with a 40-character hash, which obviously will validate as being longer than the minLength.

Answer (score 0):

use my change password behavior. it takes care of all those things at a single and clean place:
http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/08/25/working-with-passwords-in-cakephp/

you will most certainly have more problems later on otherwise
because you need a lost password and change password functionality as well.
and maybe a backend for the admin to simply change passwords as well

and to your problem i already commented:
"you should also use last=>true here! otherwise it doesnt make much sense"
i believe this is also part of your problem. all your rules need this param to make it work properly. the error messages will be off otherwise.